# How to Prompt for Committer Name & E-mail from Git Precommit Hook?

Tags: git, githooks

In our project, we have a common folder that is used by multiple developers in addition to developer specific folders. Once in a while, somebody will have to make changes in this common folder. The git config in this common folder doesn't have the user.name and user.email fields set.

So, whenever the developer makes a commit from common folder, the pre-commit hook prompts for developer's id from which it automatically determines user name and e-mail with the help of another script. Unfortunately, Git picks the previous user name and email for the current commit. For example, consider the scenario below.

1. Developer 1 tries to commit. Pre-commit hook prompts and developer 1 enters his id. Git does the commit. When I check the commit history, the user name and email will be "unknown" (assuming that was the very first commit in that folder).
2. Developer 2 tries to commit after developer 1. Now, commit history will have developer 1's name and e-mail for developer 2's commit.

It looks like git already decided on what user name and password to use before calling the pre-commit hook. Is there any way to solve this?

This is the pre-commit hook I have tried:

```
#!/bin/sh
dev_name=""
dev_email=""

git config --remove-section  user #To remove any entry that exists in the config file
read -p "[pre-commit hook] Shared repo - please enter your ID:" this_id
#Call the script that determines user name and password from $this_id

#Update git config with the current user's info
git config user.name "$dev_name"
git config user.email "$dev_email"
```

Comment: Maybe another alternative is having (honor system?) the developer run a bash script with their ID when first starting to work on the common folder?

Comment: If no other method is possible, I will do this. Thank you.

Comment: Yea, its definitely not the best alternative -- but I'm not much of a git hook expert..

Comment: I tried adding 
    "git commit -n --amend --author "Unni <Unni@unni.com>" -C HEAD"
in post-commit hook.

While it does modify the user name and email, it goes into an infinite loop in prepare-commit-msg hook. I had added a echo line in prepare-commit-msg hook. That line keeps on getting displayed in bash repeatedly.

Comment: That's not really an infinite loop in prepare-commit-msg.  Instead, your post-commit hook runs `git commit` (with `--amend` etc), which makes a new commit, which mean git runs the post-commit hook, which uses `git commit`, which makes a new commit so that git runs the post-commit hook, etc.  So you're making an endless series of new commits each time.  You need a way to tell your own post-commit hook not to keep firing off new commits.

Comment: Do your users share the same user-account to access the folder?

Comment: @torek Thanks. Will see if there are any ways I can make the post-commit hook not run the second time. Would you recommend any methods?

@ florianb: We have a bunch of test PCs. They all have the the same user account. Developers login with the common user name on the PC. Everybody thus have access to the folder.

Comment: If you're really set on this approach (I'd try to find one that doesn't require an automatic amend in the first place), an appropriate way of breaking the loop is to do the amend only if the existing commit doesn't match the desired commit.  In other words, only if author-of-HEAD != desired-author, commit --amend --author=desired-author.  (But this leaves you with a race condition: if someone else is trying to do a commit in the shared account at the same time, the HEAD commit may change on you.)